# Liferay 6.2 Hook deployment strange behaviour

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6

I have deployed a document library hook which includes many jsp files under custom_jsps.

Recently, I wanted to change folder_action.jsp, so I changed it and deployed it normally in document library portlet.
As it was expected, a folder_action.portal.jsp was created containing the original file.

However, I've noticed something strange. After stopping Tomcat both folder_action.jsp and folder_action.portal.jsp are deleted(this is not happening for the other files that come from the hook), and when it is up again a really strange thing happens. The folder_action.portal.jsp contains the changed file and the folder_action.jsp is the original file.

Has anyone met something similar ever? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might run into a very nasty issue: You must only override a particular jsp from exactly one hook. If you override the same jsp from two different hooks, the scenario that you describe might happen (on undeploy). Worse: Order is not maintained, you might have some "wrong" files left over.

Find the two hooks that override the same jsp and determine which you like better (or merge the two). Find some more horror in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399323/how-to-resolve-conflict-between-hooks-modifying-the-same-jsp/25403916#25403916) to a similar question

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately, there is no other hook that overrides the specific jsp. What is normally expected when the specific jsp is deleted manually from portlet after Tomcat is stopped? I see that Liferay creates again folder_action and folder_action.portal after starting Tomcat again. Where does Liferay find the original file since it is deleted from portlet?

Comment: If *both* files (folder_action.jsp and folder_action.portal.jsp) are *not* there when all hooks are undeployed and *are* there when all hooks are deployed, you *definitely* have two hooks that contain the same jsp (folder_action.jsp).

Comment: You are right. My hook changes folder_action.jsp which is also overriden by portal-compat-hook. The thing is that portal-compat-hook is a default liferay hook and I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to remove folder_action.jsp from there, so that my hook changes take effect.